# Not able to set cookies in session

Tags: python, python-requests

I am web scraping an ecomm - website where the product list is varies on user location. I need to set location by setting cookie value, but unable to achieve the desired results

```
import requests
import urllib3

#    Cust_Cookies={'_bb_cid':'19'}
    
#    cookie_jar=requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
#    cookie_jar.set('_bb_cid','19',domain='.bigbasket.com',path='/')

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

response1=requests.get('https://www.bigbasket.com/custompage/sysgenpd/?type=pc&slug=fresh-vegetables',verify=False)
print(response1.cookies)

print(response1.cookies['_bb_cid'])
ssn=requests.Session()
ssn.post('https://www.bigbasket.com/')
print('session cookies before edit:\n',ssn.cookies['_bb_cid'])
ssn.cookies.set('_bb_cid','19',domain='.bigbasket.com',path='/')
print('session cookies after edit:\n',ssn.cookies['_bb_cid'])
response2=ssn.get('https://www.bigbasket.com/custompage/sysgenpd/?type=pc&slug=fresh-vegetables',verify=False)
print(response2.cookies)

print(response2.cookies['_bb_cid'])
print(response1.json()['tab_info'][0]['product_info']['p_count'])
print(response2.json()['tab_info'][0]['product_info']['p_count'])
```

Above sample should ideally return products for Mumbai City in repsonse1 (because i am **scraping** from Mumbai City with cityid as 4)
where as for response2, it should consider Anand as city and accordingly the products should be listed.
To verify, i just printed the count of the products in the JSON result which should be different for both the cities
but with above code, i am getting same results in both the response.
was expecting the value of cookie - _bb_cid in both the case should be different

Comment: you might look at the python requests module.

There you can use a session, which will store and send the gathered cookies for you.

https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: thats what is done in the above example

Comment: I don't underastand what you're doing with the cookie jar How is this cookiejar linked to the session

Comment: cookie jar though defined in above code is not getting used. i tried using cookie jar as well while calling the ssn.get / ssn.post. the above code has residual code wrt cookie jar should be ignored. will comment the same post editing

Comment: why do you perform the first request outside of the session and only the other requests in the session.

If you want to 'capture' the cookies set by the first requiest you should  use session.get instet of requests.fet

Comment: my previous comment might be the reason why things don't work as you expect.

Comment: @gelonida above code is a sample code. Original code is much larger where I have a single request called in the session. In above code I wanted to compare data hence using outside the Session. Expected is that result in both the response should be different

Comment: I still don't understand. It is very rare, that the first request of a session is a post. normally thr fitdst get provides you with session cookies or alike. then normally you post your request.

I think best thing is if you add comments in your code (or print statements to show exactly where you expected o have which cookie value and which cookie value we got.

You might to do  same requests in an anonymous browser window and compare the results.  If there's no weird java script on the  site you should be able to reproduce the issue in the browser.

Comment: @gelonida tx for the response. I will be traveling for next 2 weeks    will work on it once am back from my vacation